# Find the mouse position in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, mouse

I'm stuck with the following.
I'm programming a game and I need to get the mouse pointer location inside the JFrame, I don't need to get the pointer location on the screen, but just in the JFrame. When you use the MouseClick event you could get the position in the frame while the mouse button is pressed, but I want to get it's location when no button is pressed.
I hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html).
The [MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) contains the current mouse position.

```
void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
```

> Invoked when the mouse cursor has been moved onto a component but no buttons have been pushed.

Comment: You could also get the mouse location on screen then bound it to the JFrame.

Comment: Ok, thansk. I didn't noticed that this mouse moved event was avaiblable, I checked the docs of java and I didn't found it. But thanks, I'll check it soon, if it works I'll vote this as an answer.